# resetting a shared preference value to null in android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

If I was to set a key/value pair in android preferences what would be the best way to go back and unset the value to null while maintaining the key? what I would like to do is set and unset the value programmatically, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its as simple as:

```
yourEditor.remove("your key to remove");
```

and you must remember to commit as usual:

```
yourEditor.commit();
```

Comment: Also, setting NULL for a shared preference is equivalent to removing it